# AngularJS - Multiple controllers watching route changes

Tags: angularjs

From what I've read, Angular doesn't support multiple views out of the box for URL changes.

What I really want is to have a set of controllers in charge of different parts of the application UI, that each respond in their own way to route changes.

Is there a common solution for this, or am I thinking about the application structure in the wrong way?

The ui-router plugin doesn't appear (to me) to solve this particular problem in the way I'd like - it's a state-first approach with optional URL changes, as opposed to URL-first.

Comment: Why not watch for location changes in each controller and act accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular actually does support multiple views out of the box, what it doesn't support is multiple `ng-view` out of the box.  You can use `ng-include` and place a controller on that element and watch for any route changes you need.

Essentially you'd do something like this:

```
<ng-include src='"menu.html"' ng-controller='MenuCtrl'></ng-include>
<div ng-view></div>
```

The ng-include's controller you would be watching for route changing and doing whatever is needed.

The ng-view of course is driven by the route changes setup in your app config.